# Angular ngAnimate how to hide element after ngHide animation?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ng-hide

Currently when an element is hidden via ng-hide, first the element gets display="none" then the animation happens. Is there a way for display="none" to be added once the animation is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common suggestion is to add a `display: block !important` rule for the `.ng-hide-add , .ng-hide-remove` classes. The add and remove versions of hide class are added by `ng-animate` and removed after the relevant animation.

Sources: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

http://ng.malsup.com/#!/css-animations-for-ng-hide_ng-show